# Overwrite similar methods, shorter syntax

Tags: ruby

In a Ruby Class I overwrite three methods, and, in each method, I basically do the same thing:

```
class ExampleClass

  def confirmation_required?
    is_allowed && super
  end

  def postpone_email_change?
    is_allowed && super
  end

  def reconfirmation_required?
    is_allowed && super
  end

end
```

Is there a more compact syntax? How can I shorten the code?

Comment: If your code works and you want a code review you should consider moving this to [codereview.se].

Comment: I would be interested to see a solution that used a technique similar to all the rails methods. Something like "require_confirmation :postpone_email_change? :reconfirmation_required? :confirmation_required?"

Comment: @JeffPrice rails is ridiculous, but still, please: `Extender = Module.new {def require_confirmation(*methods); methods.each { |m| define_method m { |*args, &cb| is_allowed && super(*args, &cb) } };  end ; module_function :require_confirmation }`. Now call `Extender.require_confirmation :postpone_email_change?, :reconfirmation_required?, :confirmation_required?` or `prepend` the `ExampleClass.singleton_class` with `Extender` and call it without an explicit namespace.

Answer (score 7):

How about to use alias?

```
class ExampleClass

  def confirmation_required?
    is_allowed && super
  end

  alias postpone_email_change? confirmation_required?
  alias reconfirmation_required? confirmation_required?
end
```

Comment: Did you try that code? Would be interesting to know whether "alias" actually calls the correct super.

Comment: A wee problem with your answer: it's wrong. Suppose `class A; def x; puts "in A#x"; end; def y; puts "in A#y"; end; end; class B < A; def x; super; end; alias y x; end`. Then `B.new.y #=> "in A#x"`. Heungju (and @Felix), why did't you test?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ExampleClass
  %i|confirmation_required?
     postpone_email_change?
     reconfirmation_required?|.each do |m|

    define_method m do |*args, &cb|
      is_allowed && super(*args, &cb)
    end
  end
end
```

**Note:** The `%i|symbol1 symbol2|` is shortcut for `[:symbol1, :symbol2]` - it is ruby 2.0+ syntax for creating a list of symbols from words.

Comment: The `%i` syntax might need explanation for newer bees.

Comment: Mudsie, you can't use an implicit `super` with `define_method` (recall `"RuntimeError: implicit argument passing of super from method defined by define_method() is not supported. Specify all arguments explicitly."`) Fortunately, since `m` has no arguments and no block, the fix is easy: replace `super` with `super()`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you! Updated. The arguments can be easily repassed in general way, though, please see an update.

Comment: The generalization was helpful (for me, anyway).

Comment: @Felix it’s language syntax basics, there is no trick, no cumbersome code, no nothing: it’s just a plain old good ruby syntax. I believe, that understanding the syntax of the language one is using, is like a must.

Comment: @mudasobwa: plain old ruby 2.0 syntax but no need to argue.

Comment: @mudasobwa Anyway I edited your answer, feel free to revert.

Answer (score 0):

The `eval` approach. Considered a code smell but has better readability in this case. Also easier to understand for the less experienced folks on your team.

```
class ExampleClass
  WRAPPED_METHODS = %i(
    confirmation_required?
    postpone_email_change?
    reconfirmation_required?
  )

  WRAPPED_METHODS.each do |method_name|
    class_eval("
      def #{method_name}
        is_allowed && super
      end
    ")
  end
end
```

Comment: So, you took my [at the moment incorrect, now it’s correct, thanks to @CarySwoveland] answer, make it worse by ridiculous call to `eval` where it does completely not belong to, and posted as your own? What’s the reason of doing that? If you want to execute a string here, use `class_eval`/`instance_eval`. Also, it **does not read better** without syntax highlighting.

Comment: I was working on this exact type of problem a few days ago, so no, my answer is not 'inspired' by yours. One of the concerns I had was that my code would be handed over to a team of junior programmers, and it would be tricky for them to navigate the quirks of `define_method` and `super()`.

Comment: So, your concern is to educate juniors with doing `eval` instead of proper rubyish solutions everywhere because it’s hard to understand `super`? Got it.

Comment: Where do you think `eval` belongs then? I did mention it was a code smell and this particular approach was in the interest of clarity. No need to pass extraneous arguments or parentheses to super.

Comment: `eval` belongs to ruby 0.9 when no `instance_eval`/`class_eval` existed.

Comment: So would changing `eval` to `class_eval` legitimize this answer from your perspective?

Comment: Using string evaluation instead of invented for this specific purpose `define_method` makes code less readable and less expressive; but using `eval` instead of `class_eval` in 2017 is a nonsence :) I won’t consider this answer being of any value, but I will retract the downvote for changing `eval` to `class_eval`.

Comment: No issues with that. For what it's worth, I ended up implementing the `define_method` approach with empty parentheses for my code. Lol.